# ZMQ notify on subscribe

Tags: callback, notifications, publish-subscribe, zeromq

I am using a ZMQ PUB socket to distribute news on different topics. But some of these messages are expensive to compute. Is there a way to have an on_subscribe callback so I can calculate only what is actually needed?

Answer (score 3):

Just to document the solution that I found

I can create an XPUB socket and listen for incoming messages on that socket. Subscriptions will generate a message starting with b'\x01' followed by the topic. When a client unsubscribe, the message will be b'\x00' followed by the topic.

Comment: Note that you can also do this using ROUTER-DEALER, if you're prepared to manage the subscriptions yourself.

Comment: I tried to do the same (using XPub-Sub model). But, I am getting only one notification when the first client subscribes to it not on all subscription. Can you help me to know what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the XPUB and XSUB sockets is documented in [the zmq_socket man page](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-socket#toc11).

There's also an example in the Guide that uses XPUB like this to do [last value caching](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Last-Value-Caching).

Answer (score 0):

in zmq 2.x subscriptions are not sent to the publisher(s). zmq 3.x has subscription forwarding, but there is no such callback at the publisher site.

Comment: I found a way. It is not a callback but does the trick. See my response.

Answer (score 0):

the way you create the on_subscribe callback is by setting up another req/rep connection between the publisher and any connecting subscriber. The subscriber will send what messages it wants to the publisher to let it know what messages it should prepare for publishing. This way only the messages of interest will be published over the PUB/SUB connections. Its a sort of what to 'register' which messages you are going to want instead of blasting all messages.

Comment: I found a way without using a REP/REQ, see my response.

Comment: Better to switch to 0MQ/3.2 and use the XPUB socket.